# Yii2 Rules customization

Tags: yii2

I have a rule like this

```
public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [ [ 'movie_id']'required' ],
            ];
        }
```

and in my form if i don't select movie i get 'movie cannot be blank'. how can i change that sentence to a custom one?

```
 public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return [
                'id'              => Yii::t( 'app', 'Movie' ),
                   ];
        }
```

i think if i change the value in attributelabels i can change it, is there any other way i can change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function rules()
{
      return [
           [ [ 'movie_id'], 'required', 'message' => 'your-custom-message' ],
      ];
}
```